# Conditional logic on whether to include subclass

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to edit the init.pp file to only include a subclass if a variable has been set.  I've initialized the variables as undef, however when I do the IF statement as below it errors and says:

> Syntax error at 'if'; expected '}'

When I write it as a case statement, it works fine but not as an IF.  Any idea why that is?

```
  class {'wlsvr':
  }
  ->
  case $jdbc_filename {
    undef: {}
    default: {class {'jdbc':}}
  }
  ->
  if $managedsvr_name != undef {
    class {'managedsvr':
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please rid yourself of the unfortunate habit of using

```
->
```

between every other Puppet statement.

This [chainging arrow](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ordering.html#chaining-arrows) introduces a *dependency* between the resources/classes it connects. This should be used only when a dependency is actually needed. Issues you are opening yourself to

- gratuitous dependency trees when building dependencies between classes (you do that here)
- issues when refactoring code, because `if` and `cases` statements do not (always) form the equivalent of resources or classes

As an aside, it is also beneficial to avoid the

```
class { 'classname': }
```

syntax for declaring classes and prefer

```
include classname
```

instead, because the former costs you the [singleton semantics](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html#include-like-vs-resource-like) of Puppet classes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The chaining arrow is required at the moment although I need to figure out exactly where the explicit dependencies need to be and where they can be run in another order.  I've changed to use the include.

Any idea why the if aren't working when the case is though?

Answer (score 0):

Using an chaining arrow before an `if` statement is illegal syntax. From the puppet documentation on [Relationships and Ordering](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html#language:-relationships-and-ordering):

> #### Operands
>
> The chaining arrows accept the following types of operands on either side of the arrow:
>
> - Resource references, including multi-resource references
> - Resource declarations
> - Resource collectors

I'm not sure why it allows `case` statements and not `if` statements, but I don't think it's best practice to chain either of them.